# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket on new openshift

Tags: mysql, ruby, openshift, redmine

I am trying to set up the same instance of redmine I had running on the old openshift. I have set up everything as far as I understand but I am not great at this and I think I have configured the database incorrectly.

My database config is here

https://github.com/Dunkhan/Redmine/blob/master/config/database.yml

The error I get is

> Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

I know there are a lot of questions already posted with this error but most of them involve php so none of those solutions are applicable, in addition, these questions are mostly several years old and openshift has completely changed recently. I tried some of the solutions like changing to root user for mysql, and adding in the port to the config, but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Your MySQL instance runs in a separate pod. You can't use local UNIX socket. Instead use INET connection. The hostname will be the name of the Service your your MySQL instance. Have you tried anything like that? IOW, what have you tried setting the environment variable ``MYSQL_SERVICE_HOST`` in your deployment to?

Comment: MYSQL_SERVICE_HOST is currently set to mysql.my-application.svc

Comment: Add if you set it to just ``mysql``? Or are you using ``StatefulSet`` for deploying MySQL and a headless ``Service``? Or is your project called ``my-application``? Either way, if in same project you can just use ``mysql`` if that is the name of the ``Service`` object for MySQL instance.

Comment: BTW, what even expands the ``database.yml`` file so your environment variables get populated?

Comment: changing the MYSQL_SERVICE HOST to just mysql did not fix the issue.
My application is not called my-application,  I just substituted that. The actual text in the environment variable is the actual name of the application.
As far as I understand (which is not far), the database.yml file will be read by the redmine framework somehow.  I have the syntax from a help document I found but I am far from sure it is correct. It is possible these aren't being expanded and that is the issue